# Insert Into queries take too much time in Apache spark

Tags: java, oracle, apache-spark

I am using Oracle Database with Apache spark 2.3.0

In my code I am writing final output (after all the processing) in **three tables** using below spark command.

```
billableChargeKDF.write().mode("append").format("jdbc").option("url", connection).option("dbtable", "CI_BILL_CHG_K").save();
billableChargeDF.write().mode("append").format("jdbc").option("url", connection).option("dbtable", "CI_BILL_CHG").save();
billableChargeSqDF.write().mode("append").format("jdbc").option("url", connection).option("dbtable", "CI_BCHG_SQ").save();
```

Each of the three Dataframes has 130 Partions. Each dataframe is writing **30 Million rows.**

I am using **130 Cores, 26 Executors (Each executor is having 30GB Memory), 2 Worker machines(each having 88 virtual cores and 502.GB Memory)**

After analyzing **`AWR report`** I found that above `INSERT INTO` queries takes most per Execution time.

**Is there anyway I can reduce same?**

**Is there anyway I can improve performance?**

**EDIT**

Also High Watermark contention is 30% of DB time.

DB machine has **16 Cores and 264GB.**

**AWR REPORT DATA**

[image: AWR image 1]

[image: AWR image 2]

Comment: You might get better answers for this on the Database Administrators Stack Exchange site - https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @PlayerOne can I ask same question there?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I think you have to close this one first or get a mod to migrate it

Answer (score -1):

Could you please try with below settings?

> executor cores: 25
>
> cores per executor : 5
>
> executer memory - 35G

total 130 Cores- let's leave one core and assign each executor 5 cores, meaning

```
125 Cores/5 => 25 Executors with 5 cores each.
1004 GB Memory => 1004/25 => 40.16 - (40.16 * 0.07 for system) =37.36 Lets assign 35G for each executor.
```

Comment: Actually we have 2 worker nodes so 26 Executors means 13 on each worker for even distribution.